# SEO friendly URLs with "-"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, seo, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am trying to address a problem of seo-friendly urls. Here are the templates:

- http://www.example.com/{city}-{state}/
- http://www.example.com/{city}-{state}-{zip}/
- http://www.example.com/{area/district}-{city}-{state}/

Both {city} and {area / district} can contain multiple words were spaces are replaced with '-' symbols.

Here are a couple of examples:

- http://www.example.com/babylon-ny/
- http://www.example.com/new-york-ny/
- http://www.example.com/some-other-city-az/
- http://www.example.com/the-district-the-city-az/

Default routing mechanism does not seem to be addressing this problem. Additionally, there is a Html.RouteLink functionality that would be nice retain.

What is the best way to address this problem?

PS: I know that it is easier to use "/{state}/{city}/" pattern but there is no way I can use it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure this sorta thing is handled with Route Constraints.

Here's an article that shows something similar of what you're trying to do
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/641783/Customizing-Routes-in-ASP-NET-MVC

Here's also a SO question dealing with the same sorta thing
[ASP.NET MVC regex route constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561266/asp-net-mvc-regex-route-constraint)

Since cities can have spaces leading to multiple dashes, you might have to go the full blown route of adding a your own custom constraint (inherit from `IRouteConstraint`)  Then within the match method just take last to characters and convert them to your state from there.  The first codepoject article should have an example of the custom constraints.

That might look something like this

**RouteConfig.cs**

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    //we're basically telling it to capture everything here with the {*customRoute},
    //then we're also passing that route to the Action
    routes.MapRoute("CityStates", "{*customRoute}",
        new { controller = "CityStateController", action = "MyAction", customRoute = UrlParameter.Optional},
        new { customRoute = new CityStateConstraint()});
}
```

**CityStateConstraint.cs**

```
public class CityStateContraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values,
            RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        //return true if it is one of the city-states you handle
        //false otherwise
    }
}
```

In this example the route would be passed to your action, and you could handle splitting the city and state from there...you would probably want to make it so it passes the city and state separately so your actions are cleaner.  But hopefully this gives you an idea.

It might be possible to do this in a different easier way as well, but someone more knowledgeable in mvc routes will have to chime in.

Comment: that is a good way to do this. What worries me is that if we start adding more routes into play it will become a lot messier. Think of the following examples: "{city}-{county}-{state}", "{district/area}-{city}-{state}", "{city}-{state}-{zip}", etc.

Comment: Another thing I am looking for is to use Html.RouteLink helper methods to generate route-compatible urls.